# How to reload all favicons in Firefox Quantum Bookmarks

Tags: firefox, browser

This question is related to the deprecation of the ***Favicon Reloader*** Firefox extension.

I know that [this](https://superuser.com/questions/440682/reload-of-firefox-bookmarks-favicons) can be a effective solution, but as it's mentioned, is really high resources consumption at loading too much pages at the same time.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1523158/439537 Checkmarks extension is still good: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/checkmarks-web-ext/